# Windows 8.1 makes mu cpu run at 110% of its max clock speed... normal?

Tags: clock, windows-8.1

I bought a i5-4570 cpu, which features a nominal max clock speed of 3,2 GHz and, as fa as I know, it doesn't support overclock. But Windows 8.1 makes the cpu run faster, up to 3,6 GHz. Is it normal? Do I risk ho have my cpu damaged?

Here's a screenshot of cpu-z while moving a 60K polys model in Blender 3D...
[cpu-z screenshot](https://imageshack.com/i/0eetrip)

Comment: This is a question for serverfault.com

Comment: Sorry - you're asking in the wrong place; this site is for programming. That said, I believe what you're seeing is a feature of the newer intel CPUs called [TurboBoost](http://www.makeuseof.com/tag/forced-induction-intel-turbo-boost-works-technology-explained/), which whacks up the clock speed under heavy load.

Answer (score 1):

Its not overclock, but "Turbo", which is a built-in feature of the processor, and not Windows 8.1.

Check below link:

http://ark.intel.com/products/75043/

```
Clock Speed             3.2 GHz
Max Turbo Frequency     3.6 GHz
```